# why hull white model has normal distribution?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance

consider hull white model $dr(t)=[\theta(t)-\alpha(t)r(t)]dt+\sigma(t)dW(t)$
when we solve the SDE above we have $r(t)=e^{-\alpha t}r(0)+\frac{\theta}{\alpha}(1-e^{-\alpha t})+\sigma e^{-\alpha t}\int_{0}^{t}e^{\alpha u}dW(u) $ and when we take expectation and variance we have $r(t) \sim N(e^{-\alpha t}r(0)+\frac{\theta}{\alpha}(1-e^{-\alpha t}),\frac{\sigma^2}{2\alpha}(1-e^{-\alpha t}))$.

I know the calculate how find SDE and find expectation or variance but
i don't understand why $r(t)$ has normal distribution.

thanks.

Comment: Is it correct to assume that you know that the innovations $dW$ are normally distributed?  And you likely know that the sum of normally distributed random variables is also a normally distributed random variable.

Comment: the stochastic integral term is a normally distributed r.v. search for integration of deterministic functions wrt Brownian motion to see why.

Comment: @ peter : adding to calculon's comment, if you look for Wiener Integral you will find all that you need to answer the question yourself. Best regards